# Copying files in order by last modified

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I'm trying to move a bunch of files from a directory to my phone in a specific order so it wouldn't mess up the order in my phone.

The furthest I've gotten is by using this command:

```
find . -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | sed 's@^.*/@@' | xargs -I{} cp "{}" '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_RF8NA3063PJ/Internal storage/Music/music'
```

or this one

```
stat -c "%Y/%n" *.mp3 | sort -t/ -k1,1n |sed 's@^.*/@@' | xargs -I{} cp "{}" '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_RF8NA3063PJ/Internal storage/Music/music'
```

The problem is that once the filename includes an apostrophe, I get the following error:
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

I understand that when I'm using "find" command I need to add a -print0, but doing this

```
find . -print0 "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | sed 's@^.*/@@' | xargs -I{} cp "{}" '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_RF8NA3063PJ/Internal storage/Music/music'
```

Gives me an error: find: paths must precede expression: `%T@ %p\n'

Turning the command into this works but messes up the order

```
find * -print0 -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | sed 's@^.*/@@'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer I'm considering the following command of yours as our starting point:

> ```
> find . -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | sed 's@^.*/@@' | xargs -I{} cp …
> ```

Then you write:

> I understand that when I'm using "find" command I need to add a `-print0`

and then you try:

> ```
> find . -print0 "%T@ %p\n" | …
> ```

or:

> ```
> find * -print0 -printf "%T@ %p\n" | …
> ```

I think the main misunderstanding is in "I need to *add* a `-print0`". No, you don't add `-print0`. In cases (examples) where `-print0` appears and seems to be added, it really *replaces* an implicit `-print`. The point is `-print` is the default action and in many cases you don't have to type it. Then, if you want to replace it with `-print0`, you append `-print0`. The existence of `-print0` suppresses the default `-print`. It looks as if `-print0` was added, but logically it replaced `-print`.

In your case the `-printf …` already suppresses the default `-print`. This means there is no `-print` in your command. If you add `-print0` (like you did), you will have `-printf …` and `-print0` and each one will print something.

You don't want to simply replace your `-printf …` with `-print0`, because for you the point of having `-printf …` instead of (explicit or implicit) `-print` is this `%T` you used. You want to *modify* your `-printf …`, so the new `-printf …` with respect to the old `-printf …` is exactly like `-print0` with respect to `-print`.

What is the difference between `-print0` and `-print`? The former uses one trailing null byte as the terminator, where the latter uses one trailing newline character. `-print0` is equivalent to `-printf '%p\0'` and `-print` is equivalent to `-printf '%p\n'`

Your  `-printf "%T@ %p\n"` exactly uses one trailing newline character, it's `-print`-like. To make it `-print0`-like and retain the `%T`, you just need to change `\n` into `\0`:

```
find . -printf '%T@ %p\0'
```

Then you need to make your `sort`, `sed` and `xargs` work with null-terminated lines. Hopefully if your `find` is rich enough to support `-print0` and `-printf` then your other tools are also capable of handling null-terminated data. And I assume your `cp` supports `-t`. Effectively I assume GNU tools.

This is the command:

```
find . -iname '*.mp3' -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' \
| sort -zn | sed -z 's@^[^ ]* @@' \
| xargs -r0 cp -t '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_RF8NA3063PJ/Internal storage/Music/music'
```

Note I changed the `sed` code. Your code removes everything up to the last `/` (`.*` is greedy!), so only the last component survives, the filename (except for `.` where there is no `/`, so everything survives!). If there are files matching `-iname '*.mp3' -type f` in subdirectories then passing only the last component will make `cp` fail. My code removes everything up to and including the first space, i.e. the fragment resulting from `%T@` . Everything resulting from `%p` survives. This means that:

- files in subdirectories can be copied,
- but a name collision (if any) will make the later `cp` overwrite, so eventually some files may be missing in the target location;
- pathname components starting with `-` are safe (i.e. we don't need [double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/108618)) because all pathnames start with `.` anyway.

I used `-iname '*.mp3'` because elsewhere you used `*.mp3`. I used `-type f` because its a sane thing to do (you certainly don't want to process paths to directories and pass them to `cp`).

I believe if there is a pathname that forms an invalid text in your locale then you need `LC_ALL=C`, for `-iname '*.mp3'` to work as expected. I'm not sure about `sed`. If you want to work with such pathnames, consider `export LC_ALL=C` beforehand.

Comment: Thanks. Immensely informative post for me, I have a feeling I'm going to re-read this post multiple times in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here is my comment:
I tested it in a small directory and I see `find .` gives you back the ˙.˙ which don't have `/` in it, so I think your sed messes up.
Here is my test:

```
find . -printf "%T@ %p\n" |sort -n
1650024944.2971079410 ./.nvmrc
1650108929.2884298980 ./package.json
1650108929.2884298980 ./package-lock.json
1657746711.8129748630 .

find . -printf "%T@ %p\n" |sort -n |sed 's@^.*/@@'
.nvmrc
package.json
package-lock.json
1657746711.8129748630 .
```

Maybe not the most efficient solution:

```
find . -printf "%T@ %p\n" |sort -n |grep -v ' \.$' |sed 's@^.*/@@'
.nvmrc
package.json
package-lock.json
```

UPDATE:
I think this will work. You were very close, just missed `-printf` where you used `-print0`. And the `grep -v` solution doesn't work with `-print0` so I added `! -path .` to find to exclude the `.`

```
find . ! -path . -print0 -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | sed 's@^.*/@@' | xargs -I{} cp "{}" '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_RF8NA3063PJ/Internal storage/Music/music'
```

Comment: If I add the ' xargs -I{} cp ...' at the end I still run into the same problem: "xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
"

Comment: Check the update

Comment: The same problem when not using the -0 option on the xargs, also it's in alphabetical order now.
If I use the -0 option on xargs, it prints everything together and gives me an error "File name too long"

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" \
    | sort -n \
    | sed "s:^[^ ]* ::;s:\":\\\\\":g;s:^:cp -t target-directory \":;s:$:\":" \
    | bash
```

Explanations:

1. **find** command:

- **-type f** - only search files, not directories

2. **sed** command:

- **s:^[^ ]* ::** - remove the leading stuff
- **s:":\\\\\":g** - change doublequote to \"
- **s:^:cp -t target-directory \":** -- add prefix
- **s:$:\":** - and add suffix

I have to pipe to `bash` instead of using `xargs` because I could not deal with those quote/doublequote in `xargs`. Sorry for that. Please read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385466/properly-escaping-output-from-pipe-in-xargs

(sorry for my broken English)